# how to extract variable lengh of strings from file in datasatage using substring or index function

Tags: sql, oracle, datastage

Input :

```
start1
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
start2
```

I want to capture whatever string is in between start1 and start2. String between them would be variable. 
Output:

```
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
```

**Using Substring/Index function**

Comment: What is the difference between start1 and start2? What is to extract in between?

Comment: you load this file into a table, and looking for some SQL?  Not sure what your asking exactly

Comment: I cant's use tables, this is small piece of code. I got stuck in between. satrt1 and start2 are starting and ending postions which I know. But string between start1 and start2 would be of variable length. I want to extract that string between start1 and start2

Comment: @Pooja - Again, what do you need to substring? It is impossible to understand your question. What is in between david@gmail.com and david@gmail.com?

Comment: Art, Please dont look at the data , it's dummy data. what I need is to capture the data between start1 and start2. If it can be done using Index functuion then also it would be ok, Does my description make any sense ?

Comment: @Pooja - you need to provide some real example using dummy data. Then it is possible to help you. It is impossible even to imagine what is in between start1 and start2 may be. Are there any specific characters, numbers in between. What is in between?

Comment: @Art, There will be email_ids in between start1 and start2 like: start1 sam@23456.com,sam@23456.net,Jue@23456.net,Rass@23456.com Jue@23456.net,david@yahoo.com start2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its in pl/sql then you can do this:

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_str varchar2(2000) := 'start1
  3  david@gmail.com
  4  david@gmail.com
  5  david@gmail.com
  6  david@gmail.com
  7  david@gmail.com
  8  david@gmail.com
  9  david@gmail.com
 10  start2';
 11    v_newstr varchar2(2000);
 12    v_start_delim varchar2(10) := 'start1';
 13    v_end_delim varchar2(10) := 'start2';
 14  begin
 15    v_newstr := substr(v_str, instr(v_str, v_start_delim)+length(v_start_delim),
 16                       instr(v_str, v_end_delim) - instr(v_str, v_start_delim) - length(v_start_delim));
 17
 18    -- remove leading/trailing breaks.
 19    v_newstr := trim(both chr(10) from v_newstr);
 20    dbms_output.put_line(v_newstr);
 21
 22  end;
 23  /
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

or if you had the string in SQL (assuming the string is all in one row)

```
SQL> select trim(both chr(10) from
 2           substr(str, instr(str, 'start1')+length('start1'),
 3                instr(str, 'start2') - instr(str, 'start1') - length('start1'))
 4         ) newstr
 5    from data;

NEWSTR
-----------------------
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you *must* use an order by.  By the rules of SQL, if you do not use an order by, then a database can return the results in *any* order, even different than the last time you did the same query.

Assuming you do an order by id, and the field name you are querying is name

```
select name
from table1
where id > (select id from table1 where name = 'start1')
  and id < (select id from table1 where name = 'start2')
order by id
```

Comment: Hi Marlin, could you please suggest me the same using Substring function ?

Comment: The way the question is shown there is no place to use substring.  Your description indicates that you have these values in the field of a table.

Comment: I have got these values using Script and I want to use the substring function in datasatge. So I would be grateful if you suggest it using substring function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here as it is impossible to understand what is required:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(str, start1+1, btwn_starts)) final_str
  FROM
  (
  SELECT 'start1 '||' some data in between '||' start2' str
        , Length('start1') start1
        , Length('start2') start2 
        , Length(' some data in between ') btwn_starts
    FROM dual
  )
 /

Output string: some data in between
```

Comment: there will be Email_Id's between start1 and start2. Lengh is not fixed.

Comment: @Pooja - replace string 'some data in between' with 'david@gmail.com' in inner query and you will get it in output. This is the best I can do as I still do not see the whole picture, sorry. it is up to you to make it clear.